Solution to Carroll's Pillow Problem (elementary number theory)
I was skipping through a few pages of Lewis Carroll's pillow problems, and came across this (not a very complex problem):
"Prove that 3 times the sum of three squares is also the sum of 4 squares."
How do you prove it?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

I've tried to prove it, but all my attempts were unsuccessful. What context am I supposed to provide?

If you got stuck after a few steps, show what you have tried (that is the basic version). There are lots of questions that get posted here, the ones that explain what has already been tried and why the question may be of interest to other users are the ones that get the most attention and get answered quickest, in general.

Thank you for helping me out. I'll try to edit my question soon.

See https://nrich.maths.org/problems/sums-squares for possible hints. It also has the generalizations as well as the constricted case, which might be easier to think about.
@bluemonday

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Thanks, I'll check it out. @noobman

First I thought "What nonsense is this", but while trying I stumbled upon $3 \cdot (1^2+2^2+3^2)=2^2+2^2+2^2+6^2$, but you must admit: if equal numbers are allowed in the four squares, that should also be the case for the three squares, and I can't imagine four squares adding up to $9$, being ($3 \cdot (1^2+1^2+1^2)$), or am I missing something?

@Dominique if you allow repetition of numbers in the three squares then you need to allow $0^2$ as one or more of the four squares but otherwise it works well.

So, perhaps a better phrasing of the question is that three times the sum of three different squares is always the sum of four squares?

$3(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}) = (x+y+z)^{2} + (x-y)^{2} + (y-z)^{2} + (x-z)^{2}$

@conan: that's not a comment, that's the answer :-)

Writing this answer for completion. In short,
$$3(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}) = (x + y + z)^{2} + (x - y)^{2} + (y - z)^{2} + (x-z)^{2}$$
What I did to arrive here was represent $3 = 1^{2} + 1^{2} + 1^{2} + 0^{2} = (1 + i + j)(1 - i - j)$ and $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = (x + yi + zj)(x - yi - zj)$, where $i,j,k$ are quarternions. Multiplying $1 \pm i \pm j$ with $x \pm yi \pm zj$ leads to expressions of the form $(x + y + z)^{2} \pm (x - y)i \pm (z - x)j \pm (y - z)k$. Its only natural to then see if $(x + y + z)^{2} + (x - y)^{2} + (y - z)^{2} = 3(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2})$, in which it is. This method used is similar to how you can derive Pythagorean triples.
